# BI publisher, Issue with repeating field in PDF template

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I'm having issue with repeating field in PDF template.
Below is the part that I defined repeating erea.

[image]

This is the 'BODY_START' field.

[image]

This is the 'BODY_END' field.

[image]

This is the repeating field 'ITEM_CD'.

[image]

Here is the data structure.

[image]

BTW, I'm using document repeat element tag on the top-left of the PDF template.

[image]
[image]

The toolkit :

I followed the below document.

[Oracle official document](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12211/bip/BIPRD/GUID-6379E5BD-1CE4-4F9D-B311-F33098866FE6.htm#BIPRD2860)

It's very appreciated if anyone can give me some hint why the 'ITEM_CD' is not repeating.
I viewed the data in data model. There where more than 2 rows.

Comment: Can you turn on grid lines and retake the screen shot? Also, I think you want to use compatibility mode with the desktop tool. All your code is behind the scenes with the "rep-field" stuff. Oracle really complicated stuff with that. I think it's an option in the Word BI Publisher desktop tool. Finally, please give an example of the data, and your expected output.

Comment: @EdHayes3 Thank you very much for the comment. But I’m using PDF template, editing the template using Acrobat, not RTF template edited by word desktop plugin. Are you familiar with PDF template? If so, I will take some screenshots more detailed.

Comment: I have never used a PDF template. I'm only familiar with RTF templates in Word, or eTEXT templates.

Comment: Can you check the value of **psxp_pdf_optimized** under peopletools setting of report definition. If it is set to true, please change it to false and check once.

Comment: @SaiPatil Thank you for the replay. I couldn't find 'peopletools setting' on my BI publisher UI. Can you show me where is this setting? Where is the button or link?